# How to send data from a HTML form via PHP to a file?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, subscribe

Basically, I am creating my own email list, I've set the HTML up, but now I've been looking for 30 minutes now, how to send the Full Name and Email Address to a file via PHP. I need to enter details in HTML, send them to PHP, then off to a file or MySQL Database, I'm not sure which one I have to use yet, but I'd prefer to use a file.

Code (HTML):

```
       <form class="emailsub" action="subscribe.php" method="POST">
            <h1>Subscribe</h1>
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Full Name">
            <input type="text" name="" placeholder="Email Address">
            <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

I need some PHP code that will do what I need, obviously I have all the other HTML layout, css links, and all that, but all I need is a .PHP file that I can use to grab data from a form, send it to a file or MySQL Database.

Thanks.

Comment: For retrieving form submission data from php, you need to call $_POST or $_GET of methods

Comment: Reading and writing files can have unexpected side effects. You would be advised by most to use a database. You will, if you look, find thousands of articles detailing how to save data to either a database or textfile.

Comment: Let me guess, you want to make a contact form/newsletter form work via php and you don't know any PHP?

Comment: https://html.form.guide/php-form/php-form-processing/

It's too dangerous to process data without any validation. So be carefully when you reading and processing data from $_POST variable. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the data to a file, you can try this code

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $text = $name . "," . $email . "\n";
    $fp = fopen('data.txt', 'a+');
    if(fwrite($fp, $text))  {
        echo 'Saved!';
    }
    fclose ($fp);    
}

?>
```

But I recomend you to use MySQL Database.

Answer (score 0):

This form is sending the data to the file via POST, so in the PHP file you can access it through the $_POST variable, check the [documentation here](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.post.php).

The input fields should have some name defined so you can get the info:

```
$myField = $_POST["field_name"];
```

To store the data in a file you can use file_put_contents funcion, [check this out](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php).

Answer (score 0):

Add names to form fields, delete name from submit button.

```
<form class="emailsub" action="subscribe.php" method="POST">
    <h1>Subscribe</h1>
    <input type="text" name="full_name" placeholder="Full Name">
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now in subscribe.php file you can access data like below:

```
<?php
if(isset[$_POST["submit"])) {
    $fullName = $_POST['full_name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];

    // do anything with $fullName and $email
}
?>
```